# Bullet navigation in image slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

In below code when i click any of the bullet it will start with that bullet id and just after it will start with the first image means from beginning. Can you update that code in such a way if i click on the second **bullet** after second the loop will start from 3 itself means the next after the clicked one.

here is My [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4STr/1/)

```
 <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="1" data-slide="1">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="2" data-slide="2">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="3" data-slide="3">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="4" data-slide="4">4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e4STr/1/

Comment: __Can you update that code__ why do we work for you? Better option to hire someone.

Comment: i found problem in that..any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

In going through your fiddle, I noticed that your variable 'id' is a being stored as a string and in your showSlide function you are trying to concatenate a string with and integer here:

```
sliderNext = id + 1;
```

Meaning the value that you assign to the global variable sliderNext is going to be something like 21 or 31 or 41. So when you call startSlider, this logic will always evaluate to True:

```
if(sliderNext > count){
   sliderNext = 1; // set to beginning after completion of slides list
   sliderInt = 1; // set the Integer number back to 1 also
}
```

Essentially resetting the value back to 1 every time. You could use something like parseInt on the 'id' variable and then it should work fine.